# Is it possible to measure accurate Milliseconds time between few code statements using python?

Tags: python-2.7, delay, pyserial, milliseconds

I am developing a python application using Python2.7.
That application is using pyserial library to read some data bytes from serial port.
Using while loop to read 1 byte of data in each iteration. In each iteration
I have to measure execution time between statements if it is less than 10 ms wait for it to reach 10ms before starting next iteration. there are two questions here as follows:

1. Time measurement

What would be the best way to measure time between python statements to the accuracy (1ms or 2ms difference acceptable) of milliseconds.

2. Time delay

How can i use that measured time for delay in order to wait till total time is 10ms (total time = 10ms = code execution time+delay)

I have tried time library but it does not give a good resolution when in millisecond some time it does not give anything when small time duration.
for example:

```
import time
while uart.is_open:
uart.read() 
start = time.time()
#user code will go here

end = time.time()
execution_time=end - start
if execution_time< 10ms:
remaining_time = 10ms - execution_time
delay(remaining_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a string that is minutes:seconds:microseconds using `datetime` like so:

```
import datetime
string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S:%f")
```

And then turn it into a number to make comparison more handy:

```
m, s, u = string.split(":")
time_us = float(m)/60e6 + float(s)/1e6 + float(u)
```

In your example, that would look like this:

```
import datetime
def time_us_now():
    h, m, s, u = (float(string) for string in datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S:%f").split(":"))
    return h/3600e6 + m/60e6 + s/1e6 + u

start = time_us_now()
# User code will go here.
end = time_us_now()
execution_time = end - start
```

Comment: Hi @Guimoute your suggested solution Not giving right timing. For multiple variations output is coming as 1000 event that is not consistent as it changes to 0 in some instances for same scenario.

Comment: What does "output is coming as 1000 event" mean? I added hour support in case your test starts in a given hour and ends in the next.

Comment: by printing the execution time output prints 1000. It does not change as expected with addition of more tasks in between time measurement.

Comment: That is unexpected... Especially if it's always exactly 1000. I'm in Python 3.6 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I have managed to get upto 1ms resolution by doing two things.

1. Changed (increased) the baud rate to 115200 from 19200.
2. Used time.clock() rather than time.time() as it has more accuracy and resolution.